# How to display a number in indian rupees format using java

Tags: java, number-formatting

In my code finally amount will be generated. I want to display it in indian rupees format like 
                   10
                   100
                   1,000
                   10,000
                   1,00,000
                   10,00,000
                   1,00,00,000
                   10,00,00,000 etc. How can i insert commas ?
 eg: int amount=1000;

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using `locale` like

Here you can use any locale for your case it should be `en_IN`

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(paramDouble);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the java.text.DecimalFormat

and do something like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(###,##0);
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
dfs.setGroupingSeparator(',');
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
df.format(numberToFormat);
```